# Trying send mail from Theme page

Tags: php, theme-development, email

I am trying to send an email and parse its contents using `WP_Mail` but the email is not sending, I am just not getting an error message on the page. Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with my function?

```
<?php 

    //lets get the redem voucher email that will go to both the user and                    
  $replacements = array(
'({playerId})' => $playerId,    
'({message_body})' => nl2br( stripslashes(  $ggs['player-redeem'] ) )
 );
$message = preg_replace( array_keys( $replacements ), array_values( $replacements ),  $ggs['player-redeem']);


//Handle some basic validation
$errors = array();

//Assigning a picture for {logo} replacement
$logo = 'http://fundrasing.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wp-content/themes/gogreensoccer3/images/logo.png';
$headers = 'From: My Name <test@test.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
//Send the message assigned to a var so we can output
$status = send_message( 'test@test.co.uk', 'test@test.co.uk', 'Player Wants to Redeem Points', $message, $logo );
```

I just used the default wp_mail but its not being sent as test

```
wp_mail( 'test@test.co.uk', 'The subject', 'The message' );
```

I do get other emails from the system so I know it is setup OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign `wp_mail()` to a variable you can echo the results. Should return either `true` or `false`.

```
$email = wp_mail(email,subject,message);
var_dump($email);
```

I don't recognise the `send_message()` function in your code.